# Solution for Hadamard matrix using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to build something similar to a [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) recursively and I need some assistance. I didn't find in the web any solution that do it recursively.

If someone know something or know the solution and can be kind and post it here, It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks!

Edit: 
This is a non-recursive code for this:

```
public class Hadamard
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    boolean[][] H = new boolean[N][N];
    H[0][0] = true;
    for(int n = 1; n < N; n += n)
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                H[i+n][j] = H[i][j];
                H[i][j+n] = H[i][j];
                H[i+n][j+n] = !H[i][j];
            }
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
            if(H[i][j]) System.out.print("* ");
            else        System.out.print(". ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

From: https://gist.github.com/guitarkitten/3937264

Comment: Do you have a code that builds it non-recursively?

Comment: Why do you want to do it recursively, if you have the code for the non-recursive case? In most cases, non-recursive functions are easier to handle and can be computed for larger input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if anyone will tackle this question trying to find a solution, I found a pretty clean and good one for this.
The idea is to call four recursive calls, one for each quarter of the matrix (every Hadamard matrix is divided to four cells, top-left is 1, top-right is 1, bottom-left is 1, and bottom-right is -1). So the first three calls fills the positive 1's, and the fourth fill is with (-1)*sign.

```
public static void fillHadamard (int mat[][])
{
    fillHadamard(mat, 0,0,mat.length, 1); //overloading, assuming mat.length is pow of 2 
}
private static void fillHadamard (int [][] mat, int top, int left, int size, int sign)
{
    if (size == 1)
        mat[top][left] = sign;
    else
    {
       fillHadamard (mat, top, left, size/2, sign);
       fillHadamard (mat, top+size/2, left, size/2, sign);
       fillHadamard (mat, top, left+size/2, size/2, sign);
       fillHadamard (mat, top+size/2, left+size/2, size/2, (-1)*sign);
    }
}
```

Look how clean and neat this compering to none-recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation based on the recursive definition for Hadamard matrices whose dimension is a power of 2.

```
H(0)  = [1]

       | H(k-1)     H(k-1) |
H(k) = |                   |
       | H(k-1)    -H(k-1) |
```

I've substituted `true` for 1 and `false` for -1 to be consistent with yours.  Also note that I'm using the Hadamard index number `k` rather than the dimension `N`.

```
public class Hadamard {
  public static boolean[][] hadamard(int k) {
    if (k > 0) {
      boolean[][] a = hadamard(k - 1);
      int dim = a.length;
      boolean[][] h = new boolean[2*dim][2*dim];
      for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < dim; ++j) {
          h[i][j] = a[i][j];
          h[i][j + dim] = a[i][j];
          h[i + dim][j] = a[i][j];
          h[i + dim][j + dim] = !a[i][j];
        }
      }
      return h;
    } else {
      return new boolean[][]{{true}};
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] H = hadamard(4);
    for(int i = 0; i < H.length; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < H[i].length; j++) {
        if(H[i][j]) System.out.print("* ");
        else        System.out.print(". ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Running this produces:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* . * . * . * . * . * . * . * . 
* * . . * * . . * * . . * * . . 
* . . * * . . * * . . * * . . * 
* * * * . . . . * * * * . . . . 
* . * . . * . * * . * . . * . * 
* * . . . . * * * * . . . . * * 
* . . * . * * . * . . * . * * . 
* * * * * * * * . . . . . . . . 
* . * . * . * . . * . * . * . * 
* * . . * * . . . . * * . . * * 
* . . * * . . * . * * . . * * . 
* * * * . . . . . . . . * * * * 
* . * . . * . * . * . * * . * . 
* * . . . . * * . . * * * * . . 
* . . * . * * . . * * . * . . *
```

Comment: It's an answer, not a comment.  The code works, produces valid Hadamard matrices, and is recursive, i.e., it's everything you requested.

Comment: What do you want? I said thank you. about the "comment" thing don't be petty please. The reason I didn't mark this as accepted answer is because I found a better solution.